# Configure PhpStorm to connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I want to use PhpStorm to connect to mysql, but I only can connect through it to mysql running on localhost. How do I configure PhpStorm to connect to mysql running on a remote server?

Comment: On phpstorm, nothing different with local and server. you need to check remote server setting to connect your desktop with another tools(e.g. mysql-workbench)

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure
its  fault.

Comment: have you tried with workbench?
OR try with telnet 'telnet remote-server-ip remote-server-port'

Answer (score 0):

I like to connect to my database over SSH. Just go from the Database sidepanel to the 'Data Sources and Drivers' window. Create a new datasource with the host set to 'localhost', then go in the 'SSH/SSL' tab and enable 'Use SSH tunnel' with your SSH connection params.